# Different camera sizes in same file

Tags: rendering, camera, dimensions

I know render dimensions are tied to the render settings, but for my architecture scenes it would be very handy to have the option to assign different aspect ratios to different cameras, all in the same scene. Is there a way to do this? (without having to use the timeline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those interested: we now use the Photographer addon for this purpose. It is no longer free but still very cheap and I couldn't recommend it enough.

The main purpose of the addon is to provide artists with tools that resemble real life cameras a lot more. You can read more about al its functionalities on the addon's page (link below) but the part that is relevant for this specific issue is the Resolution settings. Basically all the addon's settings can be customized for each seperate camera, and this includes some options for the render's resolution. The settings of the active camera will override the resolution settings in the Scene tab.

I find that just this one function already makes the creative process of finding a good angle much easier.

Available at: https://blendermarket.com/products/photographer

[image]
(Don't worry, it has a "custom" resolution mode as well ;). )

Comment: Thanks for posting. Do you mind adding more detail and explain how do you use it and what's the real advantage in this case?

Comment: @brockmann I edited the post with more information

Comment: Would there be any other alternative to photographer (free) that would ONLY allow to add per camera resolution ? This is the only needed functionnality i need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can't rule it out 100% but I would be very surprised if you could do this per camera. You can change the sensor width and height in the camera settings, but that should not change the aspect in the rendering.

The only solution that comes to mind is a script that hardcodes the desired resolution (and with that the aspect ratio) for each camera and set it up as a driver. Meaning when you hit render it will check which camera is active and assign the resolution that you referenced to that camera.
Let me know if that is an option, then I would try to work out that script. Also: untested, there might be one more step to that. Worst comes to worst we create a tiny script that acts as a render button but does the adaption to your scene before render (that one will work for sure).